# question of sed replace

Tags: linux, sed

i have a config file xml

> ```
> <tflow name="CENTRE"
>      inputDTD="/JOBS/cnav/etc/jobReporting/batch/dtd/dtd-ContactCentre.dtd"
>      inputFile="/JOBS/cnav/etc/jobReporting/import/2010.05.02.CONTACTCENTRE.xml"
>                  logPath="/JOBS/cnav/etc/jobReporting/logs/"
>                  rejectPath="/JOBS/cnav/etc/jobReporting/rejets/"/>
>             <tflow name="SKILL"
>                  inputDTD="/JOBS/cnav/etc/jobReporting/batch/dtd/dtd-Skill.dtd"
>                  inputFile="/JOBS/cnav/etc/jobReporting/import/2010.05.02.SKILLS.xml"
>                  logPath="/JOBS/cnav/etc/jobReporting/logs/"
>                  rejectPath="/JOBS/cnav/etc/jobReporting/rejets/"/>
> ```

my shell is aim to change, by example '2010.05.02.SKILLS.xml' with 'newdate.SKILLS.xml'

currently i think of SED, i wrote:

```
sed 's/(import\/)(\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2})/$1$newdate/g' myfile.xml
```

it doesn't work,i test the pattern with RegExr(a site) which is fine.

is it a problem of synthesis of SED?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many regex dialects around... I think *sed* does not understand `\d`. Besides, use `\1` for the bactracking, and use double quotes if `$newdate` is a shell variable. And try `-r` to use extended regex.

Try something like this

```
   sed -r "s/(import\/)([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})/\1$newdate/g" myfile.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Most sed implementations don't support extended regexps by default, so you need to use basic regexps.  This means you need to put backslashes before your parentheses and braces, and you can't use the `\d` class.  You also have the syntax of backreferences wrong -- it should be `\1`, not `$1$`.  So, it should look like this:

```
 sed 's/\(import\/\)\([0-9]\{4\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\)/\1newdate/' myfile.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your sed implementation, you may have to specify that you are using regex.  What OS/version of sed are you using?  You may, for example, have to use the -E argument.

Comment: Which version of `sed` has `-E`? By the way, `sed` *always* uses regexes. Perhaps you're thinking of *extended* regexes. Some `sed` versions use `-r` to enable that. `grep` does have `-E` - maybe that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, you probably know this by now, but just for posterity, it's the *BSD family of seds that gave us `-E`. I believe it was introduced in both FreeBSD and NetBSD in 1993. The `-r` option was added to help with compatibility with GNU sed around 2006 for NetBSD, 2009 for FreeBSD and 2010 for OpenBSD, but this addition hasn't made it to OS X, which still only has `-E` for ERE. The origin of this was the radical thought that command line tools might use a common switch for common functionality, and `-E` was already established as the ERE switch in grep.